# How do I use await inside a generator?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-6, generator

I'm having a generator that, among other operations, queries a database, like

```
function* current(db) {
  const items = await db.collection('...').find({ ... });

  for (const item of items)
    if (...) yield item;
}
```

which isn't valid syntax. Using promises and yielding from a `then`, isn't possible either.

What should I do then? How can I use asynchronous operation inside a generator?

Comment: Nope, you can't combine `async` with generator functions in ES6 and ES7.

Comment: Of course I can't. But is it possible to solve my problem at all? I want to make a database-dependent generator, and fetching data from a database is an asynchronous operation. Am I out of options then?

Comment: There are some ES proposals lurking around on how to make such things work. Have a look at https://github.com/kriskowal/gtor. You'll be able to hand-craft yourself, maybe even using either `await` or `yield`, but I guess it won't be too simple or clean.

Comment: To be fair, there is now a possibility to make async generators in Node 10, so it solves the problem I have, although I’m not sure if I have a generic enough and common enough problem right now.

Comment: @rm-: I have the same problem (hence the bounty): `await` the result of a DB call, then yield out results from a loop.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Calling `await` in generators (aka async generators) has been supported natively in Node v10+ (released [April 2018](http://2ality.com/2018/04/async-iter-nodejs.html)) and [Chrome since v63, as well as Firefox v57](https://medium.com/dailyjs/decoupling-business-logic-using-async-generators-cc257f80ab33).

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function getAsyncData() {
  await sleep(1000);  // simulate database/network delay...
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];  // ...then return some data
}

// async generator
async function* filterAsyncData() {
  const items = await getAsyncData();  // await call in generator
  
  for (const item of items)
    if (item % 2) yield item;
}

(async function main() {
  // for-await syntax
  for await (const filteredItem of filterAsyncData())
    console.log(filteredItem);
  
  // classic iterator syntax
  const fadIt = filterAsyncData();
  while (true) {
    const result = await fadIt.next();  // note await
    if (result.done) break;
    console.log(result.value);
  }
}());
```

Compared to a regular (non-async) generators, remember to use `await` before calling `.next()`. Alternatively, the new [`for-await-of`](http://2ality.com/2017/12/for-await-of-sync-iterables.html) syntax has been available since Node v9.2, and can be used in Node v10 without any flags.

For older versions of node (or for Jest), you can use the Babel plugin [transform-async-generator-functions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-async-generator-functions).

Comment: I think that's it!

Answer (score -2):

You can't combine async with a generator function. That said you most likely don't want to be using a generator in your case and instead just have an async function:

```
async function current(db) {
  while (true) {
    const latest = await db.collection('messages').findOne({}, {
      sort: {
        timestamp: -1
      }
    });

    return smth;
  }
}
```

The generator *will be generated for you* when the `async` is transpiled.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that you could in Babel 5. Babel 6 not support this until recently... I believe 6.17.0.

Comment: This `while (true)` loop makes no sense, your function `return`s in the first iteration.